# Disabling ClickFailed screenshots in capybara-webkit

Tags: javascript, ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

Is there a way to disable capybara-webkit from creating a screenshot(click_failed_XXXXXX) when a ClickFailed error occurs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends

If you never need it in the current execution environment you could always overwrite it

```
module Capybara::Webkit
  class Driver
     def save_screenshot(path, options={})
     end
  end
end
```

This should do the trick (haven't tested it)